# Error when creating array in java in IntelliJ: Error: Groovyc: unexpected token: 1

Tags: java, arrays, groovy, enums

I just want to simply create an array:

```
int[] nums = {1, 2, 3};
```

But there is an error:

> Error: Groovyc: unexpected token: 1

What should I do? Thank you!

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

class ArrayTest {
    @Test
    public void demonstrateArray(){
        int[] nums = {1, 2, 3};
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your @Test, you have to comment that out, "//@Test"

Comment: Firstly, the fact that it says Groovyc suggests you may be in the wrong language. Also where is the error occurring? I reckon its due to you incorrectly instantiating the array. Should be `new int[]{1,2,3}`

Comment: Hi Wookies-Will-Code, Thank you, but @Test is a junit annotation for my test class , i will not comment that out.

Comment: Hi 615283, thank you, but     new int[]{1,2,3}      does not work. Theoretically people should be able to create array either      int[ ] myArray = new int [3];      or     int[ ] myArray = {1,2,3};         but i do not know what it the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groovy supports arrays just like in Java but instead of `{}`, use `[]`. Initialize array with `[]`

```
class ArrayTest {
    @Test
    public void demonstrateArray() {
        int[] nums = [1, 2, 3];
    }
}
```

Comment: I see evidence for groovy but this is only tagged java and he did not specify.

Comment: _I see evidence for groovy_

Comment: Thank you!!!!! It works!!!!!!!!!!!!!! But in my text book, { } is used, how can [ ] work? I do not understand why it can work. would you please help me?

Comment: @pradipforever Hi, thank you!!!!! I finally find out what is wrong, i created .groovy instead of .java file..... problem solved, thank you again!

Comment: you are welcome. Also in groovy 3.0, you can use Java-style array initialization like:  `def nums= new int[] {1, 2, 3} `